# Getting the recordset into an XML using VBScript

Tags: sql, xml, vbscript, xmldom

My SQL query returns a single column result which is actually an XML. When I click on the recordset, it opens up a `results.xml`.

This is the output XML I am grabbing into `result_string` by using

```vb
result_string = objRecordSet.Fields(colname).Value
```

```xml
<TEST_SUITE SUITE_ID="122675741" PART_NUMBER="MTSTE-26248-00" REVISION="A"     SUITE_TYPE="PRODUCTION" SUITE_NAME="HOT-LOW" SUITE_STOP_ON_FAIL="TRUE" TARGET_DURATION="0" SEQUENCE="1" UPDATED="2016-12-15T00:21:46.510">
  <SUITE_DESCRIPTION>"HOT-LOW"</SUITE_DESCRIPTION>
  <TESTS>
    <TEST TEST_ID="122663528" TEST_NAME="Set Suite Environment Variables" PART_NUMBER="MTTST-65899-00" REVISION="A" MODULE="TEST Set Environment Variables.vi" MODULE_LIBRARY="BIG-IP_TESTS" TEST_STOP_ON_FAIL="TRUE"   TEST_TYPE="BEGIN_SESSION">
      <PARAMETERS>
        <PARAMETER PARAMETER_ID="122663469" PARAMETER_NAME="TOS" PARAMETER_VALUE="build_2.0.1.1647.0_centos6_x86_64" />
        <PARAMETER PARAMETER_ID="82137" PARAMETER_NAME="chain" PARAMETER_VALUE="TRUE" />
      </PARAMETERS>
      <MEASUREMENTS>
        <MEASUREMENT MEASUREMENT_ID="70784" MEASUREMENT_NAME="TOS" UNITS="" UPPER_LIMIT="" LOWER_LIMIT="" COMPARISON="LOG" INPUT_SCALE_FACTOR="" OUTPUT_SCALE_FACTOR="" />
        <MEASUREMENT MEASUREMENT_ID="81537" MEASUREMENT_NAME="chain" UNITS="" UPPER_LIMIT="" LOWER_LIMIT="" COMPARISON="LOG" INPUT_SCALE_FACTOR="" OUTPUT_SCALE_FACTOR="" />
      </MEASUREMENTS>
    </TEST>
  </TESTS>
</TEST_SUITE>
```

from this I need one Test_ID. How can I store into XML this `result_string` and get the Test_ID. Or is there any easy way to get the Test_ID?

I did something like this, but not sure if this is correct, and also I am getting an error on line `objCommand.Execute ,, adExecuteStream`.

```vb
Dim strm  
Set strm = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")

strm.Open

Set objCommand.ActiveConnection = objConnection
objCommand.CommandText = script_testID
objCommand.Properties("Output Stream")= strm
objCommand.Properties("Output Encoding") = "UTF-8"
objCommand.Properties("XML Root") = "Root"  'this can be anything you want

objCommand.CommandType = 4
objCommand.Execute ,, adExecuteStream
strm.Position = 0
text = strm.ReadText
Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
xmlDoc.Async = "false"

xmlDoc.LoadXML(strm.ReadText)
strm.Close : Set strm = Nothing
Set objCommand = Nothing
```

Comment: Actually the question is about XML parsing and isn't related with SQL and recordsets, so SQL tag is irrelevant.

Comment: Try `test_id = Split(Split(result_string, "TEST_ID=""", 2)(1), """", 2)(0)`

Comment: Wow, thank you @omegastripes. Really appreciate your prompt help.

Answer (score 0):

You're already parsing the XML data, so you can easily extract the value like this:

```vb
...
xmlDoc.LoadXML(strm.ReadText)

test_id = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//TEST/@TEST_ID").Value
...
```

I would recommend using `Msxml2.DOMDocument` instead of the deprecated `Microsoft.XMLDOM`, though, and I also recommend checking for parse errors before working with the data:

```vb
...
Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")
xmlDoc.Async = False
xmlDoc.LoadXML strm.ReadText

If xmlDoc.ParseError <> 0 Then
    WScript.Echo xmlDoc.ParseError.Reason
    WScript.Quit 1
End If

test_id = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//TEST/@TEST_ID").Value
...
```

Note that the [XPath expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086.aspx) (`//TEST/@TEST_ID`) is case-sensitive.

Comment: still getting the error at objCommand.Execute ,, adExecuteStream

Syntax error or access violation

Comment: Did you define `adExecuteStream`? VBScript doesn't know that constant. Otherwise try with the numeric value:`objCommand.Execute ,, 1024`. If that doesn't help please update your question with the exact error message.

Comment: @Angar Wiechers I did try 1024 but stil i got the same error. and also how to define adExecuteStream 

This is the exact error:

    Syntax error or access violation

    Line (74): "objCommand.Execute ,, adExecuteStream".

Answer (score 0):

`test_id = Split(Split(result_string, "TEST_ID=""", 2)(1), """", 2)(0)`